# Does directionality matter in regression for cross-sectional studies?

Tags: regression, inference, causality, cross-section

I am trying to see if slow walking is associated with certain brain regions. I think it makes most sense that brain atrophy leads to slow walking, so my model would be `slow walking ~ brain atrophy`.

However, since my data is cross-sectional, does it matter if I do `brain atrophy ~ slow walking`? Are you able to draw causal inferences (directionality) from cross-sectional data or is the best you can do just show an association?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can get causal inference form cross-sectional data. But simply regressing $Y$ on $X$ is not sufficient. First, the causal problem must be well-defined, where simply looking for an association is not enough. Second, certain assumptions about the assignment mechanism (i.e., the mechanism that assigns certain unit to being treated, and other to being not treated) must hold (e.g., *unconfoundedness*, *common support*).

Regression usually allows us to causally infer if we rely on the *potential outcomes framework* (see Neyman, 1923; Rubin, 1974; Imbens and Rubin, 2015). The idea is to postulate two potential outcomes $Y(0)$ and $Y(1)$, where the former denotes the outcome that a unit experiences if she does not receive the treatment, and similarly for the latter. Then, the causal effect is simply $Y(1) - Y(0)$. We usually focus on some expectation of this difference, such as the *Average Treatment Effect* (*ATE*), which is often obtaning via a linear regression.

Although a disagreement exists on this, for the problem to be well-defined we must have some control on the $X$ variable believed to cause $Y$. For instance, a well-defined causal question may be whether a certain training program raises the salary for those who attend the program. By contrast, some researchers believe that gender cannot be the focus of a causal study, since we cannot control it (see Holland, 1986, where variables that cannot considered as cause are called "attributes"). Even if someone changes gender, that would not result in a modification of a characteristic of that person, just in the unit being considered a new unit. Again, this is debatable.

Sorry for the long digression. Anyway, going back to your question, if you are able to well-define a causal question regarding the effect of `brain atrophy` on `slow walking` in the sense mentioned above, and you have access to a sample of observations satisfying certain assumptions, then yes, you can get causal conclusions, often obtained by running the following linear regression:

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{slow walking} = \beta_0 + \delta\,  \text{brain atrophy} + \beta X + \epsilon$

Under the conditions stated above, $\delta$ corresponds to the *ATE*, and $\hat{\delta}$ is your estimated average effect.

However, there may be some problems of *endogeneity*, such as *reverse causality*, where it may be that $Y$ causes $X$, and not viceversa. If the problem is ill-defined, we just get correlations about variables, and reverse causality is a real issuem while if the problem is well-defined, then we feel sort of safe.

That being said, as far as I know causality is not a relevant concept in some fields such as medicine or biology, while it is vital in economics and other social sciences. So, it may be that you are not at all interested in all this stuff, and being able to predict your $Y$ given some $X$ is all you care about. But be aware of not talking about causality then.

**BONUS**
Linear regression under completely randomized experiment (where *unconfoundedness* and *common support* are satisfied by definition) ensures that all the technical econometric assumptions needed for the finite-sample unbiasedeness and the consistency of the OLS estimates hold by definition! So, linear regression in completely randomized experiments gives you a "good" estimate of the *ATE* (see Imbens and Rubin, 2015, something arounf chapter 6 or 7).

Comment: "causality is not a relevant concept in some fields such as medicine or biology" Causality is *central* to those fields. The study of causal inference may not be, but I would argue those are the fields where causal inference matters the *most* (i.e., because they concern intervention).

Comment: @Noah I am sure that in medicine often association is what is wanted. See for instance the effect of smoking on the probability of get cancer. Clealry, a positive correlation exists, and several studies confirm that, while causality is not certain there and lately strongly debated (e.g., selection bias may be strong). However, this does not mean that smoking has no effect on cancer, it may simply not be the direct cause in the potential outcome sense, still doctors are not saying that we can smoke with no consequences because there is (probably) not direct causation.

Comment: I also remember from the reading of _Elements of Statistical Learning_ (Hastie et al., 2009) that a lot of prediction methods (not causality) where applied in top-notch studies in the field of genetics, clearly underlying that causality was not a relevant issue there (especially for the fact that some control is needed on the causing variable, where control can be defined in different ways accoding to Mill or Aristotele, among others). Anyway, I can cite finance as another field when association (or prediction) is what we want, without considering causality.

Comment: The question of whether smoking causes lung cancer is a perfect example of a *causal* question. Just because you can't do a randomized trial, doesn't mean researchers don't care about causality. There are other ways to determine causality without having to shrug and say it's only an association. This is what the entire field of causal inference is devoted to. Doctors constantly want to know the causal effect of new medicines or procedures (or vaccines!) on health outcomes. Causality is absolutely central to these questions.

Comment: I would say finance is one of the only fields where non-causal prediction makes sense because financial analysts cannot intervene in markets, whereas many other fields are concerned with the effect of (hypothetically) intervening on some state of the world (e.g., a policy, treatment, medicine, law, or drug). All questions about mechanism are causal questions, and almost all fields are concerned with mechanism. If you think "correlation does not imply causation" is where causality ends, there is a whole world of science for you to explore :)

Comment: I respect your points, but I disagree with _all questions about mechanism are causal questions_. In medicine often the task is to being able to predict whether a person is likely to get some future disease so to intervene ex-ante, with no regard about the cause of the contraction. I by no means intended to say that medicine or biology never care about causality - maybe I could phrased it better, even if _as I know causality is not a relevant concept_ was signaling that I was not sure about this, and was not aimed to say that doctors never care about causality.

Comment: Doctors care about the causal effect of the drug or treatment they give on their patients. Even though an individual doctor may not care about the mechanism of action of a drug, medicine as a field is concerned with this, i.e., the causal chain of events that explains how the human body functions and responds to medical treatments.

Comment: Just the fact that there is a _chain of events_ imply, in a broad sense, that the first event does not cause the last one, at least directly. Everything depends on the notion of causality we are adopting (see e.g., a recent controversy between Imbens and Pearl, and the methods that must be used to recover causality; I also like the article of Holland, 1986, who briefly outlines some notions of causality, citing Mill, Aristotele and others).

Comment: Anyway, I am not here to force others to adhere to my vision, I am just simplying providing my opinion and suggesting some views on the topic. I hope the community can benefit from different standpoints.