# Use of simulation in explanatory versus predictive models

Tags: modeling, simulation, explanatory-models

I understand the important distinction between explanatory vs. predictive models. However, I often read that simulations is an important tool in risk modelling and risk analysis. How are simulations used in explanatory modelling and in predictive modelling?

I imagine that with predictive models, you may want to obtain a distribution of potential outcomes therefore rely on simulations. Is that correct? I can't figure out where simulations happen in explanatory modelling.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Questions in the SE system are supposed to be narrow & 
concrete such that they can be given a definitively 
correct, factual answer in at  most a few paragraphs. 
This isn't a site for discussions or opinions.

Comment: Hi there. I am asking for concrete examples where one may use simulations and how the use of simulations may differ depending on whether the goal is to explain or to predict. I am asking for facts, not opinions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, are we speaking of potential outcomes in prediction settings?

Potential outcomes are strictly related to a notion of causality. I will try to answer you, assuming that your *explanatory* models aim to estimate causal effects. I am not repeating the potential outcome model here, as you can find plenty of explanations online, or in academic textbooks (I highly recommend Imbens and Rubin, 2015), academic papers, or even [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565042/data-analytics-and-prediction/565053#565053) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561702/does-directionality-matter-in-regression-for-cross-sectional-studies/561716#561716) on CV.

So, simulation designs are implemented in order to investigate how different estimators (or models, or what not) perform in finite samples. Let me fastly digress on this. Usually, the main theoretical properties of estimators concern their performance *as the sample size grows*. In general, we get that the precision and the accuracy improve as the number of data instances ($N$ henceforth) gets larger and larger. These *asymptotic* properties hold for $N \rightarrow + \infty$. The concern is that it is not clear how many data points suffice in order to ensure that these properties hold, as we work with a finite $N$, i.e., with finite samples.

Hence the purpose of the simualtions. By repeatedly drawing data from the same joint distribution, and applying the estimator(s) of interest, we can analyze the finite-sample behaviour of the model(s) of interest. Clearly, usually more simualtion designs are implemented, varying the sample size, the data generating process, and what not. The idea is to understand how our estimators would behave under different circumnstances.

In prediction settings, I would say that simulation scenarios may be less worthy, as we always have the true outcomes, hence we are always able to compute test errors. By contrast, in causal analysis, the treatment effects are never observed, as we observe at most a potential outcome for each unit (what Holland, 1986, calls the fundamental problem of causal inference). Here simulating data is crucial. By doing so, we specify the data generating process of the causal effects, hence we act as if we know the "ground truth", thus being able to compute test errors. In this way, we understand whether a given model (or estimator) is able to recover the unobserved truth.